# "Прошедший(,) 2017 год", "наступивший(,) 2018 год" — запятая факультативна или строго нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Запуталась. Если с запятой после слова "новый" в такой конструкции, как "новый, 2018 год", понятно, то аналогичные ли случаи здесь:

1. С наступившим(,) 2018 годом.
2. Прошедший(,) 2017 год...

Запятая факультативна или строго нужна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что пишет Грамота.ру

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Ответы не противоречат, а дополняют друг друга. Запятая во фразе с наступающим 2007 годом ставится, если пишущий придает числительному пояснительный оттенок: с наступающим, то есть 2007 годом. Однако без пояснительного оттенка оборот тоже возможен: с наступающим 2007 годом. В этом случае слово наступающим относится ко всему обороту 2007 годом: с 2007 годом (каким?) наступающим.